# How does createBitmap (int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config) fills the Bitmap?

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

How does createBitmap (int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config) fills the Bitmap?
I want to create a Bitmap with given width and height, and I don't want to generate a casual Color array. I found that this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config) create a Bitmap without any source. 
How does this method fill the pixel of the bitmap?

Comment: Sorry @Mychele,,, i couldn't understand a single bit of your question.Can you please show some work that you have done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With zeros, which is black for RGB_565 or transparent for ARGB_888